# How do I split a list to stringS (plural)

Tags: java

I have a list of strings of dynamic length:
`List<String> processInstanceIds = new ArrayList<>();`

I have a function that doesn't accept a list as parameter, but requires one to several individual strings:

[image: function]

How can I transform this list of dynamic length to a dynamic amount of strings and pass them to the function?

`myfunction(String.join(", ", theList))` did not work as it would create **one** string instead of several.

Comment: That function you have is using varargs which accept an array as well. So convert your list to a `String[]` array and feed that to the function. Something like `processInstanceIdIn(processInstanceIds.toArray(String[]::new))` should do the trick.

Comment: Your function accepts an array. So `myfunction(processInstanceIds.toArray(new String[0]))` should be sufficient.

Comment: Btw, you should not post images of code or documentation but take the time and post it as text/nicely formatted code.

Answer (score 1):

Java varargs creates a method array parameter.
Try something like this:

```
String[] blam = yourList.toArray(processInstanceIds);

kapow.myFunction(blam);
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you could try something like below

```
processInstanceIds.toArray(new String[processInstanceIds.size()])
```